# Move images rendered on highcharts on resize

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'm adding an image to the lower right hand corner of a chart in the chart loading event using the chartWidth and chartHeight properties to calculate the left / top offsets.

```
chart.renderer.image('img.png', left, top, 30, 30).add();
```

When the browser window resizes the chart also resizes, but the image remains fixed at the position set above.  When the chart shrinks in width, I'd like to re-position the image based on the new chart width.

Is it possible to move the element using some javascript or do I have to remove it and make the above call again with the new position?

Comment: is there a way to use the following in anguar 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up storing a reference to the original width of the chart and the image.  Then on resize, I'm shifting the image by the offset of the two widths -

```
var img, originalWidth;

function chartLoad(chart) {
  var top = 100, left = 100;

  originalWidth = chart.chartWidth;
  img = chart.renderer.image('img.png', left, top, 30, 30).add();
}

function chartResize(e) {
  var offset = e.target.chartWidth - originalWidth;
  img.translate(offset, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not on resize remove the image, then once the chart is done being resized, recalculate the position and add the image back?

Comment: That's what I was doing.  I was thinking there might be a way to move it the same way you'd set top/left on a positioned html element instead of removing it from the DOM and adding a new one back in.

Comment: @Mark, my savior!