# highcharts image not resized after window resize

Tags: image, highcharts

Is there any way to resize highcharts rendered image after window resize?
I have set up a fiddle file [here](http://jsfiddle.net/38Rue/1/).

```
events: {


load: function() {
                    var img = this.renderer.image('http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/skies.jpg', (200),30,200,300); 
                    img.add();
                        }

        }
```

Click on the window restore down button, then you will see the image is not at the correct place. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664410/move-images-rendered-on-highcharts-on-resize

Answer (score 0):

try using the `redraw` event to re-size the image

<kbd>[Fiddle Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/38Rue/2/)</kbd> that should give you a start,
make sure you have a reference for the image `var img;` so you can remove it and added with the `redraw` event